# Javascript removes value of input field

Tags: javascript

I want to check when a user types   "," or "." then remove the "." or the ","
and replace it with :00

for example user types 2.5 the result should be 2:00

So far nothing special but somehow my hole input field is getting cleared just the new value **:00** is there

```
    if($('#enterTime').val().indexOf("." || ",") !=-1){
        $('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val().replace(/./g, ""));
        $('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
        $('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val() + ':00');
}
```

Comment: `.` is a special character in Regex. You need to use `\.` if you want to match a literal `.` character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` in regex means 'Any character except newline', so simply escape it using a backslash:

```
/\./g
```

You could really simplify this by doing:

```
var time = $('#enterTime');
time.val(time.val().replace(/(\.|\,)/g, ":00"));
```

In this case I have added the `|` to say 'either `,` or `.`', making your regex match both. I added the `()` to encapsulate it.

Here's a (unrelated) implementation of the regex:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text.textContent = text.textContent.replace(/(\.|\,)/g, ":00");

var text = document.getElementById('text2');
text.textContent = text.textContent.replace(/(\.|\,)/g, ":00");
```

```html
<p>The original text was: 2,</p>
<div id="text">2,</div>

<p>The original text was: 2.</p>
<div id="text2">2.</div>
```

Comment: Congratulations, 30 seconds before me with the answer I thought. Nice answer.

Comment: the problem with this is that my result now looks like this 2:005:00

Comment: @TamoDaleko No, that's not a problem with *this* - that's a problem with your software's logic.

Comment: Because this answer [does exactly what you asked in the question for it to do](http://jsfiddle.net/v7c9djbp/). It might not be what you're looking for, but you'd need to ask another question for that to be answered

Comment: This code is small and working perfectly. The OP was user enters the input. so i just tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/yeuf4w2v/). can someone explain the weird behavior of above code with input element ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
Update();
function Update() {
    var value = $('#enterTime').val();
    value = value.replace(/(\..*|\,.*)/g, ":00")
    $('#text3').text(value)
}

$('#enterTime').keyup(function () {
    Update();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='enterTime' value='2.00500'> <span id="text3"></span>
```

Comment: It works, but it seems very long for the purpose it has, and it is missing a lot of optimisations. You might as well use `replace` instead of `substring` and reduce the amount of lines.

Comment: @somethinghere. thanks for suggestion. i updated my code using your regex with small modifcation `/(\..*|\,.*)/g` , so that after `.` or `,` what ever it may be that will be replaced with `:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape special character with `\` while using in regex

```
$('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val().replace(/\./g, ":00"));
$('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val().replace(/\,/g, ":00"));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bqekpzp9/1/)

Using `||` in indexOf is incorrect. use follwing

```
if($('#enterTime').val().indexOf(".") !=-1 || $('#enterTime').val().indexOf(",") !=-1){
    $('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val().replace(/\./g, ":00"));
    $('#enterTime').val($('#enterTime').val().replace(/\,/g, ":00"));
}
```